# No installer, but site is there?

Tags: admin

OK, setting up a production server (not live yet) and I am encountering a strange issue that I have not seen previously.

**Issue:**
Installed Craft on an Ubuntu 16.10 LAMP server. When all commands for installing were completed, I tested my site with its IP address to make sure everything worked and I got the following:
[image]

Then when I got to `192.168.5.254/public/index.php/admin/install` -- which has worked on the two test servers I have built previously -- I get this:
[image]

An to make sure that I have tried another method of gaining access to the installer, I went here `192.168.5.254/admin` which redirected to `192.168.5.254/admin/login`, I get this:
[image]

Clearly Craft is working as these are not Apache 404's; however I never got the install screen at all. Just the homepage and login screen. Did I miss or mess something up during this specific install?

As usual, if you need additional information, let me know I will post it in here for visual use. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: The install process is only done when you set up the database the first time. If you've moved the database to the production environment, craft is already "installed", and /admin/install will return a 404 not found. To me it looks like everything is working as it should, what makes you think that you need to run the installation process?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and thank you for the clarification here; still a neophyte to Craft, I got all the files from the Dev who has been working on this and thought it was a  1-1 install of a vanilla site. Was not thinking about the db being previously create in staging. **Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [André](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/no-installer-but-site-is-there#comment26508_19625) pointed out, you only need to run the installer if you need Craft to create all of the necessary tables in a blank database.

If you've dumped your database from dev/staging and imported it into production, there is no need to run the installer, because the tables are already there.

If Craft sees someone try to load the installer on a site that already has a populated database like you have, it will return a 404.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on this as well. Was not thinking that since the db was created in staging, I would not need the installer for the production server. **Thank you for the clarification!**